# How to use upper bound for Bernoulli distribution?

Tags: probability

Suppose we test a prediction method, a neural set for example, on set of $n$ new test cases. Let $X_i = 1$ if the predictor is wrong and $X_i = 0$ otherwise. Then $\bar X_n = \dfrac1n \sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i$ is the observed error rate. Each $X_i$ may be regarded as a Bernoulli with unknown mean $p$. How likely is $X_i$ to not be within $ε$ of $p$? For $ε = 0.2$ and $n = 100$ the bound is $0.0625$.

Can you help me with how to use this bound?

Comment: Could you clarify the following: (a) for $\epsilon = 0.2$, do you mean the interval of "within $\epsilon$ of $p$" to be $p \pm 0.2$? This is a rather large margin of error. If your error probability is, for example, $p = 0.13$, the interval actually goes outside. (b) What is the empirically known rough estimate for $p$? Is it something like around $p = 0.4$ or around $p = 0.1$?

Comment: What do you mean by "How to use upper bound"?  It just say that the probability that  $P(0.3\geq \overline X_n\geq 0.7)\leq 0.0625$

Comment: (c) What do you mean by "... the bound is $0.0625$"? What exactly is the "bound" here? For $n = 100$, under a Gaussian model the we have roughly $\frac{\epsilon}{0.05} = 4$. Namely, not within $\epsilon$ of $p$ would be four standard deviations away, which has a probability much smaller than $0.0625$

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin this is exactly what i am thinking, but i am given this exact statement

Comment: @MuhammadFasiurrehmanSohi If you have any further questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This upper bound is just an application of Chebyshev's inequality. Without using explicit the distribution you can find an upper bound:

$${P}\left[\left|X-\mu\right|\geq \epsilon\right] \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{\epsilon^2}$$

In your case $X=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i$, where $X_i$ is bernoulli distributed as $X_i\sim Ber(p)$. Then we have $\mathbb E(X)=\ p$ and $Var(X)=\sigma^2=\frac{p\cdot (1-p)}{100}$.

---

We calculate the maximum of $\frac{p\cdot (1-p)}{100}$ to ensure that the inequality holds (worst case). We can ignore the factor $\frac{1}{100}$ here.

**I.** Derivative of $f(p)=p\cdot (1-p)=p-p^2$ and setting it equal to zero.

$f^{'}(p)=1-2p=0\Rightarrow p=0.5$

**II** Proving if it is a (relative) minimum or a (relative) maximum

$f^{''}(p)=-2$. Thus $f^{''}(0.5)=-2<0\Rightarrow \text{maximum at p=0.5}$

---

Finally we can input all values to obtain the upper bound. It is given that $\epsilon=0.2$ and we have $\sigma^2=\frac{0.5\cdot 0.5}{100}=0.0025$

$${P}\left[\left|X-0.5\right|\geq 0.2\right] \leq \frac{0.0025}{0.2^2}=0.0625$$

---

We have the random variable  $X=\frac1n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$. We want the variance. $Var\left(\frac1n \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\right)=\frac1{n^2}Var\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\right)=\frac1{n^2}\left[Var\left(  X_1\right)+Var\left(  X_2\right)+Var\left(  X_3\right)+\ldots Var(X_n)\right]$

$=\frac1{n^2}\left[n\cdot Var\left(  X_1\right)\right]=\frac1{n}\left[ Var\left(  X_1\right)\right]$

Since $X_i$ is bernoulli distributed the variance of $X_1$ is $p\cdot (1-p)$. Therefore

$$Var\left(\frac1{100} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{100} X_i\right)=\frac1{100}\cdot p\cdot (1-p)$$

Comment: Thanks, this works like charm. I was not familiar with  Chebyshev's inequality

Comment: @MuhammadFasiurrehmanSohi Please express your gratitude (if there's any) via the way of upvoting or clicking the accept (green check mark) for the post. This is not my post but you're asking so many questions in such a short time as if the world owes you anything or that people are obliged to help you. Seriously there's no reason for any user to answer your question. The least you can do is to follow the social norm within the site to give a positive feedback in the form of the (albeit virtual) upvotes or accept.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin i cant up vote the answers yet i need to get 15 reputation points. I am really sorry to everyone giving me their time. I did'n notice that tick mark and now i did click that. I am really sorry i any of you felt bad, i am not used to this amazing platform.I'll be better. You guys are really helpful.

Comment: @callculus thanks for your time and help, i am sorry i didn't know about that green tick and i still cant up vote as i dont have enough reputation points. I'll be better .Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @MuhammadFasiurrehmanSohi Thank you for the comment and the checkmark. But at the moment I have no idea for your current question, sorry.

Comment: in $p⋅(1−p)100$ why are you deviding by 100?

Comment: @MuhammadFasiurrehmanSohi I have made an edit. Please have  a look.